# How to show differentiability by function by inverse function

Tags: integration, analysis

How to show differentiability of function by its inverse function.

I know that various conditions must apply, such as f'(x) ≠ 0 and the formula for determining the derivative of the inverse function. Can someone explain to me how to show that the original function is differentiable with the statements of the inverse function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It doesn't help to just close your original question and open a new one which asks exactly the same. The inverse function theorem tells you exactly under which conditions on a function $f$, the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is differentiable. Just check these conditions and you're done.

Comment: But I don’t understand it so if f‘(x) ≠ 0 and f(x) is bijective than f(x) it is differentiable?

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable with $f(a)\neq 0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is injective in a neighborhood of $a$, and its inverse $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable near $b=f(a)$. In particular, if $f\neq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then its inverse $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Of course the range and domain don't need to be $\mathbb{R}$ as in your case of the logarithm.

Comment: So you mean by log(a)(x): f‘(x) = 1/(ln(a)*x) and f‘(x) ≠ 0 for all a from (0,infinity). Because of that f^-1(x) = a^x is differentiable in (0,infinity) and inverse from (0,infinity) so it is g‘(x) = 1/1/(ln(a)*a^x)) = ln(a)*a^x for all a of (0,infinity)

Comment: First, we have $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty$, as $a$ is fixed. Secondly, $f^{-1}(x) = a^x$ is continuously differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, not just $(0,\infty)$.  Lastly, is $g$ supposed to be $f^{-1}$?. And then again we have $(f^{-1})'(x) = \ln(a) a^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise it looks ok.

Comment: sorry it looks like I’m really stupid but can you explain why we see that the function log(a)(x) is differentiable by that inverse function?

Comment: Okay, so you need the other way around. Do you know that $x\mapsto a^x$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with derivative being $\ln(a)a^x$? As $\ln(a)a^x\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, its inverse, $\log_a(x)$ is continuously differentiable by the inverse function theorem with derivative being $\frac{1}{\ln(a)x}$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Ah, so we did the other way. We show that same way with In(a) * a^x to create the inverse function and than it is also differentiable, right?

Comment: Yes, we start with $x\mapsto a^x$ and go to its inverse $x\mapsto \log_a(x)$. Of course, you can also go the other way.

Comment: Okay it is then: Set f(x) = ln(-)*a^x, f^-1(x)= log(a)(x). Now the range of f is (0, ∞) and f‘(x) = ln(a^2)*a^x is continuous and non zero for all x. Thus f^-1(x)= log(a)(x) is differentiable on (0, ∞) and d/dx log(a)(x) = 1 /(f’(f^-1(x)) = 1 / (ln(a)^2 * a^(ln(a)*a^x)

Comment: Sorry it is: d/dx log(a)(x) = 1 /(f’(f^-1(x)) = 1 / (ln(a)^2 * a^(log(a)(x))

Comment: No, that's wrong, we have $f(x) = a^x$, like I already said above in my comment, you started with the derivative.

Comment: Oh right, Okay it is then: Set f(x) = a^x, f^-1(x)= log(a)(x). Now the range of f is (0, ∞) and f‘(x) = ln(a)*a^x is continuous and non zero for all x. Thus f^-1(x)= log(a)(x) is differentiable on (0, ∞) and d/dx log(a)(x) = 1 /(f’(f^-1(x)) = 1 / (ln(a)*’a^(log(a)(x)) = 1/(ln(a)*x)

Comment: Yes, now its correct.

Comment: Okay, Thank you very very much